# Saving images as pdf sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, sharepoint-designer

I have some images in a asset library of sharepoint server 2010.

i want to convert and save them as PDF files.

Is there any service available within sharepoint server 2010 for this just like word automation service is used for ms office documents conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a ConversionJob just now, the MSDN page has a [full list of supported formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558830.aspx)

TL;DR: no.

Comment: word automation services does not support image formats(like jpg or gif) what can i do for converting these formats to pdf

Comment: you should look for external components, I do not use any and can't recommend them but they do exist, a quick google search for PDF .NET Image converter should help.